# How to implement a black gradient on an image in iOS using swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, gradient

I am working on an iOS project where I have white labels on bright images. The problem is for bright images the white labels are not showing. Here is an example:

1. Label not showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSlrV.jpg
2. Label showing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz0qB.jpg

I think if I add a black gradient on all the image then the white labels will be visible. Can anyone help me as to how to implement the solution in Swift?

Thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add gradient on your `imageView` then you can just implement `CAGradientLayer` on your `imageView.layer`.

Try to change some values for your own custom look, but the code below is pretty much it.

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = imageView.frame
let colors = [
    UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor,
    UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
]

gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.1, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.9, y: 0.5)
gradientLayer.colors = colors

imageView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

You can change colors, add colors, change start/end-points. You can find a lot of different `CAGradientLayer`-guides on youtube or google.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
extension UILabel {
    func lblShadow(color: UIColor , radius: CGFloat, opacity: Float){
        self.textColor = color
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity

        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

usage:

```
label.lblShadow(color: UIColor.white, radius: 3, opacity: 0.75)
```